# AngularJs pluralCat

Tags: angularjs, plural

I see that there's a pluralCat in each locale file

How to use it with angularJs ? I need translations for locales 'en','de','pl'

So I could use f.e. this

```
{{cardAmount | sth?}}
```

and depending on the value of cardAmount it would turn into one output of these

```
en: 0 cards , 1 card , 2 cards , ...  
de: 0 Karten , 1 Karte , 2 Karten , ...
pl: 0 kart , 1 karta , 2 karty , ... , 5 kart
```

Where would I put my translations ? And where to put the code gluing pluralCat and my translations together

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n#

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.3.3, `$locale.pluralCat` is an internal function - I would not rely on it. I'm sure angular will have more built in localization features in the future.

In the meantime I recommend using [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/). I'm using it (with one of its plugins - `angular-translate-loader-url`) to dynamically load my translations in `JSON` form (originally from a `resx` file).

I'm translating each noun in both singular and plural form (there are also other forms, like "few" in Polish and Russian...), and using logic like `pluralCat`, deciding in runtime if I should show the translation of Card_Singular or Card_Plural, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-pluralize directive : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize

if you need it in your templates.

The directive will call $locale.pluralCat (of your current $locale) for you.

Otherwise, you can just inject $locale whenever you like and call directly $locale.pluralCat().

NB: $locale.pluralCat works fine in 1.2.x, 1.3.x and 1.4.x., unit tested with:

```
function pluralService($locale) {
    this.getPlural = function(count) {
        return $locale.pluralCat(count);
    };
}

angular.module('plurals', [])
    .service('plural', ['$locale', pluralService])
    ;



beforeEach(module('plurals'));

describe('plural', function() {

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
        this.plural = $injector.get('plural');
    }));

    it('should return correct plural category', function() {
        expect(this.plural.getPlural(1)).toBe('one');
        expect(this.plural.getPlural(5)).toBe('other');
    });

});
```